# How can I read data from AWS- Aurora postgresql as python pandas DataFrame and write the same to Oracle table?

Tags: python, python-3.x, oracle, amazon-aurora

I need to read from AWS- Aurora table and write the content to Oracle table.
My code is-

```
import pandas as pd
import psycopg2
from sqlalchemy import types, create_engine
import cx_Oracle
import sys

**# Connect to Aurora**
host = sys.argv[1]
username = sys.argv[2]
password = sys.argv[3]
database = sys.argv[4]

db_conn = psycopg2.connect(host=host, database=database, user=username, password=password)
sql = "SELECT * FROM Table_Name;"
data_df = pd.io.sql.read_sql(sql, db_conn)
print(data_df.head(2))
db_conn.close()

# Connect to Oracle and write data_df  dataframe
dsn = cx_Oracle.makedsn('10.z.y.xx', '1521', service_name='abcd')
u_name = sys.argv[5]
pwd = sys.argv[6]

conn = cx_Oracle.connect(user=u_name, password=pwd, dsn=dsn)
ora_engine = create_engine(f'oracle+cx_oracle://{u_name}:{pwd}@{dsn}', echo=True)
ora_engine.connect()
data_df.to_sql(name='oracle_table_name', con=conn)
conn.close()
```

Connect to Aurora is working but I'm unable to create engine in Oracle and write the dataframe!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is correct, due to high volume of data and low RAM being configured, it was failing.

Thanks.